# How can i embed my OpenSSL certificate in Firefox?

Tags: openssl

How can I embed my OpenSSL certificate in Firefox? When I visit my website it shows an SSL warning, but I want to rebuild Firefox a custom release so it will not show an SSL warning how can I do that?

What do I want?

If someone is using our custom firefox build our build should not show an SSL warning of our certificates generated with OpenSSL.

Is this is possible?

Comment: Please be so kind to start by reading the Help pages. As you might notice your question is considered off-topic.

Comment: Don't agree that it is off-topic.  I'm not on here much, but I understand the scope is about being a 'Super User' of computer software.  Advanced configuration of a software as widely used as Firefox, how is that off topic here?  If you think about it a little more, perhaps the answer to the question-begged is off topic.  That is, if the answer was "yes, you have to rebuild Firefox" then the answer would be off-topic, probably referred to SO or SF.  But advanced runtime configuration of software, that's what a 'Super User' does, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without needing a "custom release" of Firefox. Web browsers maintain a list of certificates that should be trusted by default; many of these certificates are included with the browser when it's installed, but you can add your own. Companies often do this with their own root CA certificates, allowing certificates issued by the company to be trusted across their network.

The following instructions are specific to Mozilla Firefox 24.0 for OS X, but should apply to any recent version of Firefox on any platform.

1. Open the Firefox preferences window. In OS X, click the **Firefox** menu and select **Preferences...**
2. Click on the **Advanced** tab
3. Click on the **certificates** tab
4. Click the **view certificates** button
5. Click the **authorities** tab
6. Click the **import...** button
7. Navigate to and select your certificate, then click **Ok**
8. Examine the certificate to be sure it's authentic, then select the appropriate trust options (only you can determine what purposes you'll trust the certificate for) and click **ok**.
9. Visit a site that uses the certificate to make sure it worked.

Each user will need to perform these steps on their own browser. If you really want to bundle extra certificates into your own, installable release of Firefox, you can read [Mozilla's Firefox Deployment documentation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Deployment:Deploying_Firefox) on the topic.